# Other background colors in ExpandableListView headers

Tags: expandablelistview

I have question how set others background colors to ExpandableListView headers?

I use code of this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Check this [example](http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2014/05/android-custom-navigation-drawer-using.html), but the expandable listview is in navigation drawer.
Hope..It may solve your problem